# How to insert image inside div in OpenCart

Tags: php, html, css, opencart, division

I've been trying to fit image inside my footer in OpenCart webstore that i've been working on, but i keep bumping into problems.

Wherever i try to fit it, it just doesnt reach it's 100% height and width.

This is the design i'm trying to create.

[image]

I'm talking about the gray picture, which includes contact info and payment methods.

This is the last code i have tried. I tried to fit div outside footer but its been a catastrophic result. Also tried to fit it inside row, which was actually the best result, but i just couldnt get height to work at 100%.

`

```html
<div id="bannercek"></div>
<div id="barvanje"></div>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <?php if ($informations) { ?>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h5><?php echo $text_information; ?></h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <?php foreach ($informations as $information) { ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>"><?php echo $information['title']; ?></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h5><?php echo $text_service; ?></h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $return; ?>"><?php echo $text_return; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $sitemap; ?>"><?php echo $text_sitemap; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--<div class="col-sm-6">
        <h5><?php echo $text_extra; ?></h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>"><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $voucher; ?>"><?php echo $text_voucher; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $affiliate; ?>"><?php echo $text_affiliate; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $special; ?>"><?php echo $text_special; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      <!--<div class="col-sm-3">
        <h5><?php echo $text_account; ?></h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $order; ?>"><?php echo $text_order; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $newsletter; ?>"><?php echo $text_newsletter; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>-->
    </div>
    <hr>
    <p><?php echo $powered; ?></p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
#barvanje{
background:#2C3A4E url('../image/footer1.png') center no-repeat;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

**Link to webpage**

proprehrana.eu

Comment: Please let us know the page that you are working on.

Comment: @ManojKumar proprehrana.eu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

**HTML**

Move the div inside footer.

```
<footer>
  <!-- Container, row code -->
  <!-- Code for the two col-sm-3 -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="barvanje"></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

Set the width and height for the image in `px`.

```
#barvanje {
  background: #2c3a4e url("../image/footer1.png") no-repeat scroll center center;
  height: 328px;
  width: 537px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #barvanje {
    position: absolute;
  }

  footer {
    height: 400px;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: yes indeed this works, but footer is now like 3times the height from the original one -.-

Comment: Try with the edited CSS hack. The problem is that the image is indeed taller than the columns. And then position the copyright accordingly.

Comment: did some magic with mine code and yours and now works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your image inside the row.
2. Make your image position absolute.
3. Make your row position relative.
4. Finally, place your image with top, left, right and bottom properties.

Comment: ill give it a try and report back